# Haskell sublist with foldr

Tags: haskell, combinations, fold

I'm trying to make a function in haskell but my goal is doing it by using foldr over list, this is an example:

```
sublistas [5,1,2] 
 [[],[2],[1],[1,2],[5],[5,2],[5,1],[5,1,2]]
```

efficiency is not an issue. What I try so far gives to me the error:

> cannot construct the infinite type .....

```
sublistas = foldr (\x rs -> [x] ++ map (x:) rs) [[]]
```

I tried a long time, maybe someone could give me some ideas here?

Comment: Did you intentionally leave out `[5,2]` because you want only contiguous sublists?

Comment: No no @Alec, I forget it, thank you, I updated the q

Comment: An equivalent without `foldr` is `sublistas = filterM (const [True, False])`

Comment: `sublists = foldr (\x l -> l ++ map (x:) l) [[]]`

Comment: O.O holly... @4castle, how that can even be posible? haha, wow! did you thinked it?

Comment: For funzies, the contiguous sublists would be `sublistas xs = tails xs >>= tail . inits`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
foldr (\x rs -> rs ++ map (x:) rs) [[]]
```

For example:

```
Prelude> foldr (\x rs -> rs ++ map (x:) rs) [[]] [5,1,2]
[[],[2],[1],[1,2],[5],[5,2],[5,1],[5,1,2]]
```

The proposed `foldr` thus works as follows: we start with a `[[]]`. Now for an element `x`, we generate the concatenation, of all lists already generated (in the first step `[]`, and these lists prepended with the element, so `[2]`).

So after a first step, we obtain `[[],[2]]`. Next we fold again and now we generate `[[],[2],[1],[1,2]]`. Finally we also work with `5`, resulting in `[[],[2],[1],[1,2],[5],[5,2],[5,1],[5,1,2]]`.

The above explanation has to be seen in a lazy manner: `rs` is not necessary calculated (first), unless that is necessary.

---

Your lambda expression `\x rs -> [x] ++ map (x:) rs` is incorrect for two reasons:

- `[x]` is a list containing a **item** of the list you provide, not a list of lists of items you provide, so a type error; and
- you should not add an `[x]` to the result anyway: you pass all elements that are already generated, together with all the elements you prepend with `x`.

Comment: That works just perfect, do you mind to explain to me, why did you put rs ++ map ... why is that? how it works?

Comment: `foldr` just traverses the list, accumulating partial result. With your example - `sublistas [5,1,2] = f 5 (f 1 ( f 2 ([[]])))`. Consider last step - `f 5 [[],[2],[1],[1,2]]` In the final result we want to see two type of sublists - whose, that have `5`, it's `map (x:) rs`, and whose do not, it's just `rs`.